# Android SimpleDateFormat always returns wrong week day

Tags: java, android, timestamp, simpledateformat, android-calendar

I have the following code:

```
String s = "08-12-2014 05:00:00"
SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",  Locale.ENGLISH);
SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, HH:mm  a");
Date oneWayTripDate = null;
try {
    oneWayTripDate = inputFormat.parse(s);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
String datetime = outputFormat.format(oneWayTripDate);
```

but for some weird reason it always returns the wrong day of the week. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: How do you expect `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"` to parse `"08-12-2014 05:00:00"` well? The pattern doesn't match.

Comment: `12` is for month or for day?

Comment: That code can't possibly work. Attempting to parse the `String s` you have shown there with `inputFormat.parse(s)` will throw a `ParseException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input `SimpleDateFormat` pattern is wrong. Given the date `08-12-2014 05:00:00` with the year part at the end, and assuming `08` is the month, the format should be:

```
SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

See the Javadoc of [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for how to define date patterns.